# Insert object in list c++

Tags: c++, list

I have this class:

```
class UserLogRecord
{
public:
  std::string timestamp;
  std::string id; 
  std::string name; 
  std::string data; 
};
```

I'm iterating one vector of strings that have my logData and for each iteration i'm saving to my list.

```
std::vector<std::string> lines = explode(filedata,'\n');
std::list<UserLogRecord* > userLogRecords;
UserLogRecord* userLogRecord = new UserLogRecord;

//vector
for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
  std::vector<std::string> elements = explode(lines[i], ';');
  userLogRecord->timestamp = elements.at(0);
  userLogRecord->id = elements.at(5);
  userLogRecord->name = elements.at(6);
  userLogRecord->data = elements.at(3);
  userLogRecords.push_back(userLogRecord);
}
```

The `Explode` function is an auxiliary function to parse filedata. My filedata only have two logs, so the `for` loop runs two times. After that, if I iterate through my list and show, for example, timestamp and id, it shows me 2 times, but the same log (the last one with the same timestamp, same id).

I'm new to C++, but what is wrong? I need to change my `UserLogRecord` to include a constructor and add elements to my class inside the loop like this:

```
UserLogRecord* userLogRecord = new UserLogRecord(elements.at(0), elements.at(5), elements.at(6), elements.at(3));
```

And then use `push_back` to add `userLogRecord` to the list? Or should my first implementation work, but I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a `std::list<UserLogRecord* >` instead of a `std::list<UserLogRecord>`?  The latter is much easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  For me its not a problem working with first. I'm not understanding why we save two times the same log (its the last log)

Comment: its not a problem for you most likely because you are not aware of it ;) I bet you dont delete that `UserLogRecord`s in the vector

Comment: i try but not solve

Answer (score 0):

Your first method should work; thought, you might want to post the expected/actual output. Its quite hard to debug without those, if you coded `explode` yourself perhaps, post that code as well as it could possibly be the cause of your problems.